# ranking by group query assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling with how the logic would work on a query I'm trying to write, could use some help!

Background:
Doing some analysis around what products repeat customers buy, and if that mix of products changes as the number of repeat purchases increases.  A customer can walk in and buy a number of different things as part of the one transaction.  Just like at the grocery store there's the one transaction, with many items bought under that transaction.

So the data looks like this:

```
CustomerEmail   TransactionID    LineNumber   Item     Price   Date
bob@aol.com     100              1            Hammer   10.00   1/1/2014
bob@aol.com     100              2            Nails     1.00   1/1/2014
bob@aol.com     100              3            wrench   12.00   1/1/2014
bob@aol.com     110              1            Saw      15.00   1/10/2014
bob@aol.com     120              1            Wood      5.00   1/11/2014
jane@gmail      200              1            Hammer   10.00   1/5/2014
Jim@gmail       200              2            Nails     1.00   1/5/2014
Jim@gmail       300              1            Screws    3.00   1/6/2014
```

What I'd like the output to look like:

```
CustomerEmail   Item      Price    TransactionNumber
bob@aol.com     Hammer    10.00    1
bob@aol.com     nails      1.00    1
bob@aol.com     wrench    12.00    1
bob@aol.com     saw       ...      2
bob@aol.com     wood               3
jane@gmail      hammer             1
jim@gmail       nails              1
jim@gmail       screws             2
```

So basically a ranking within each customer's order history, but grouped by each transaction.  Hope this makes sense.  I basically want to be able to bucket products by purchase numbers to be able to say 'customers are more likely to buy a hammer on their first transaction but nails in subsequent transactions.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: What if they decide to buy another hammer later - how will the output look like?

Comment: I think you need smth like that:
select CustomerEmail,
  Item,
  Price,
  dense_rank() over(partition by CustomerEmail order by TransactionID)
from Salse

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DENSE_RANK`

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
    CustomerEmail   VARCHAR(50),
    TransactionID   INT,
    LineNumber      INT,
    Item            VARCHAR(50),
    PRICE           NUMERIC(6,2),
    [Date]          Date
)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES
('bob@aol.com', 100, 1, 'Hammer', 10.00, '1/1/2014'), ('bob@aol.com', 100, 2, 'Nails', 1.00, '1/1/2014'),
('bob@aol.com', 100, 3, 'wrench', 12.00, '1/1/2014'), ('bob@aol.com', 110, 1, 'Saw', 15.00, '1/10/2014'),
('bob@aol.com', 120, 1, 'Wood', 5.00, '1/11/2014'), ('jane@gmail', 200, 1, 'Hammer', 10.00, '1/5/2014'),
('Jim@gmail', 200, 2, 'Nails', 1.00, '1/5/2014'), ('Jim@gmail', 300, 1, 'Screws', 3.00, '1/6/2014');

--SELECT * FROM temp

SELECT
    CustomerEmail,
    Item,
    Price,
    TransactionNumber = DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerEmail ORDER BY Date, TransactionID)
FROM temp

DROP TABLE temp
```